# How do I assign a letter to an integer?

Tags: php

I have been given the task to convert decimal to binary and hexadecimal. The binary works fine but I have trouble with assigning the number 10-15 to A-F with the hexadecimal converter.

Here is my PHP function so far:

```
function dez2hex2($zahl){
$erg2 = "";
$rest = "";
while ($zahl > 0) {
    $rest = $zahl % 16;
    $zahl = (int) ($zahl / 16);
    $erg2 = $rest . $erg2;
}

    echo '<br>'.$erg2;

}
```

Note: I tried doing it with variables but I can't get it to work and I know that there are dechex() etc. but this is my homework.

Comment: But there is a ready made function [`dechex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php).

Comment: Sounds like homework....

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea - poster actually says that it's homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is often, there are many ways to do this. I think one of the cleanest would be to use an array

```
$hex = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F');
```

Now when you calculate the number, just use `$hex[ $number ]` to get the correct hex correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your function:

```
function dez2hex2($zahl){
    $hexarr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f');
    $erg2 = "";
    $rest = "";
    while ($zahl > 0) {
        $rest = $zahl % 16;
        $zahl = (int) ($zahl / 16);
        $erg2 = $hexarr[$rest] . $erg2;
    }
    echo '<br>'.$erg2;

}
```

---

```
dez2hex2(2030); //output 7ee
echo dechex(2030); //ouput 7ee
```